# I2C protocol in mbed online IDE using two STM32F429ZI board

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded, stm32f4

I am trying to send message from slave(STM2) to my master(STM1).but it doesnot show anything on my serial terminal .just i want to send and receive data in
between master and slave

my master code:

```
#include "mbed.h"

I2C i2c(PB_9,PB_6);      
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX); 



int main() {
    const int addr = 0xA0;
    int a,b;
    char buff[10]; const char data[]="message master"; 

    i2c.frequency(10000);

    while(1) { 
    /* i2c.start();                             
        a=i2c.read(addr, buff,10,1);
        wait(1);        
        pc.printf("Read %d", a);        
        i2c.stop();                
        pc.printf("MASTER READ: %s \n\r", buff);*/         
        i2c.start();        
        b=i2c.write( addr, data, strlen(data)+1);        
        wait(0.07);          
        i2c.stop();        
        pc.printf("Write %d\n\r", b);        
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) buff[i] = 0;

        }
 }
```

My slave code:

```
#include "mbed.h"

I2C i2c(PB_9,PB_6);
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);   

int main() {    

    const char test[]= "message slave";
    char buf[10];
    int i, b;

    i2c.frequency(10000);
    slave.address(0x01);    

    while(1) {

        i = slave.receive();
        wait(0.75);

        switch (i) {

            case I2CSlave::ReadAddressed:

                slave.stop();
                b=slave.write(test, strlen(test) + 1); 
                wait(0.75);

                pc.printf("Return Slave %d", b);// only to check return value

                break;
            case I2CSlave::WriteGeneral:

                slave.stop();
                slave.read(buf, 10);
                wait(0.75);
                pc.printf("SLAVE Read G: %s\n\r", buf);
                break;
            case I2CSlave::WriteAddressed:

                slave.stop();
                slave.read(buf, 10);
                wait(0.75);
                pc.printf("SLAVE Read A: %s\n\r", buf);
                break;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) buf[i] = 0;        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sending address and slave address are not matched.

You set accessing address as `0xA0` in master, and you set the slave address as `0x01`. They have to match each other.

Also, in I2C addressing, the least significant bit is used for Read/Write bit. so the [LSB bit in the slave address is ignored](https://developer.mbed.org/users/mbed_official/code/mbed/docs/tip/group__drivers.html#ga92e99d8caf7e4e844f2be4a72d60ba40), meaning `0x01` for slave address is invalid and the slave address might be general call address, `0x00`. So try changing it to `slave.address(0xA0);` in your slave code.

Added: Don't forget to add pull up resistors on the two wires.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use 8bit addresses

```
const int addr7bit = 0x48;      // 7 bit I2C address
const int addr8bit = 0x48 << 1; // 8bit I2C address, 0x90
```

https://docs.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os-api-reference/en/latest/APIs/interfaces/digital/I2C/